# How do you print a Stack Overflow page?

Tags: support

I was trying to print this question: *[Groupby with User Defined Functions Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615760/groupby-with-user-defined-functions-pandas)*

My first attempt, using default settings from Safari, produced a column of text about 2 inches (5 cm) wide and truncated most of the code blocks. For example, this line

```
>>> people.groupby(lambda x: 'Group1' if people['b'].loc[x] > people['a'].loc[x] else 'Group2').sum()
```

printed as

```
>>> people.groupby(lambda x: 'Grou|
```

where the vertical bar represents about one pixel width of the `p`.

Printing in landscaped worked better, but there was still about a 2 inch (5 cm) margin on the left and a 4 inch (10 cm) margin on the right. There was more output:

```
>>> people.groupby(lambda x: 'Group1' if people['b'].l
```

but it was still missing a significant portion of the line.

I looked for a print button, but I did not find anything that seemed relevant.

I eventually copied the text into a plain text document and then printed that. That did not truncate the text, but it did lose a lot of the formatting.

Comment: The awful print formatting is probably [a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317013/323179).

Comment: Side note, Google Chrome does not appear to have that issue with formatting. Both this question and the linked one look fine and have all the relevant data there.

Comment: If i remember right, copying the text into Notepad++ would retain the formatting

Comment: Just don't print at all, that's so last century.

Comment: @Luuklag Yes.  But sometimes, work has restrictions about what you are allowed to do.

Comment: I think I would just click on the [edit] button, copy the markdown and save it somewhere. If I need it later, I can use my brain markdown parser or another software supported one. This way I can still copy and paste links :)

Comment: @Luuklag "Printing" also involves printing to a PDF, which can be handy at times.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A third-party service called [StackPrinter](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite) exists to help facilitate this scenario.  You can simply put the question ID in to its site and it will generate a printer-friendly version of the question.

Disclaimer:  I don't claim to know if this project actually *works*, but it exists as a resource.

Comment: It [appears to work](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=19615760&service=stackoverflow), as in all the code is on the page. +1.

Comment: It works, but the output looks absolutely horrible. It's a shame there isn't a way to get the benefit of Stack Exchange's nice layouts without having the comments truncated.